# Unity 2D instantiate prefabs order

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm instantiating enemy prefabs in waves, but when I do, the sprites are not consistent on the Z axis. Sometimes the second enemy is on top of the first one, and sometimes behind.

I want the new instance always behind the other.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you share your spawning code for mode details ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the instance position and instantiate the gameobject behind.

```
GameObject myGo1 = GameObject.Instantiate(prefabRef, Vector3.Zero,
Quaternion.Identity);

float distance = 1.0f; 
Vector3 myGo2Pos = myGo1.position - myGo1.transform.forward * distance;

GameObject myGo2 = GameObject.Instantiate(prefabRef, myGo2Pos, Quaternion.Identity);
```

For the 1st GO instatiation, where `Vector3.Zero` you can choose the position of your choice. For whatever pos and rot you instantiate `myGo1` with, the code `Vector3 myGo2Pos = myGo1.position - myGo1.forward * distance;` should instantiate the 2nd one `distance` meters behind.
Not debugged code, just for your inspiration.

Probably you might need the 2nd GO to look to the first one, in that case you can do:

```
GameObject myGo2 = GameObject.Instantiate(prefabRef, myGo2Pos, myGo1.transform.rotation);
```

Comment: Great! I'm going to give this a try. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright i figured it out. had to add a sprite renderer component like so:
**SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;**

and where i instantiate:

```
void FollowPath()
    {
        if (!isAttacking)
        {
            if (waypointIndex < waypoints.Count)
            {
                **spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                spriteRenderer.sortingOrder++;**

                Vector3 targetPosition = waypoints[waypointIndex].position;
                float delta = waveconfig.GetMoveSpeed() * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, delta);
                if (transform.position == targetPosition)
                {
                    waypointIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```